# How can I implement choice field in django model?

Tags: python, django

I want to develop a pigeon app in django and my pigeon model has status field.
For this I must define another model called Status where to store my statuses.

## My model

```
class PigeonStatus(models.Model):
    STATUSES = [
        ('Activ', 'Activ'),
        ('Lost', 'Lost'),
        ('Dead', 'Dead'),
        ('For Sale', 'For Sale')
        ]

    status = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=STATUSES, unique=True)
    in_loft = models.BooleanField('In loft?')

    def __str__(self):
    return self.status

class Pigeon(models.Model):
    pigeon_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=False, blank=False)
    band = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    ...
    status = models.ForeignKey(PigeonStatus, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
```

My question is how can I set boolean value for every status? I want to query like this: `Pigeon.status.in_loft = true`.
From choices, Activ and For Sale must have `in_loft=True` and Lost, Dead must have `in_loft=False`.
Does anyone can answer this? Is there another way(better one maybe) to set pigeon status and refer to it later?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since your `in_logt` is dependant on the value of `status` field of your `PigeonStatus` model, there is no need to create the in_loft field. A better pythonic way is to have a custom method(with property decorator) in your `PigeonStatus` to get values for in_logt. Then you can call in_loft from PigeonStatus's instance as you proposed.

Here is the example code:

```
class PigeonStatus(models.Model):
    STATUSES = [
        ('Activ', 'Activ'),
        ('Lost', 'Lost'),
        ('Dead', 'Dead'),
        ('For Sale', 'For Sale')
        ]

    status = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=STATUSES, unique=True)

    @property
    def in_loft(self):
        return self.status == 'Activ' or self.status == 'For Sale'
```